# How to unzip a password protected file in Boomi

Tags: groovy, zip, password-encryption, boomi

I am trying to read a password file present on a SFTP server and write it back to my local disk using Boomi.

But as per an [old official documentation](https://community.boomi.com/s/article/howtozipandunzipfiles),

> Creating or unzipping archives that are password protected is not supported.

I tried using Groovy script to handle it but I am unable to understand how to consume the document read by SFTP connector in my Groovy script and then write it back to disk.

I was wondering if some here in community has faced similar challenge and was able to find a solution.

Comment: If you put the zip file on a local disk you can use a Program Command shape to run a System Command to execute a command line zip program.